# Help loading images into Galleria dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, galleria

I am building a site with the gallery as the main feature, and I need the gallery to have "categories". I am going to load in the images via AJAX but at the moment just getting the Galleria gallery to load in different images is proving challenging. My code is as follows:

```
function swap_gallery() {
    var new_slideshow = [
        { image: '../images/slideshow/architecture_3.jpg' },
        { image: '../images/slideshow/report_1.jpg' }
    ];
    Galleria.get(0).load({
        data_source: new_slideshow
    });
}
```

When I run this function I get this error in Firebug:

> Error: Load failed: no data found.

For the life of me I can't work this one out.

Comment: My bad, [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/)

Answer (score 2):

Just push the new values as you would do for an array.

Galleria.get(0).push({image: '../images/slideshow/architecture_3.jpg'});

Galleria API #Manipulation http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/api/methods/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I've already ditched Galleria in favour of a different slider that I got to work.

Comment: What did you select to replace galleria?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Galleria 1.2.9.

```
Galleria.get(0).load([
        { image: '/foo/bar/image1.jpg' },
        { image: 'image2.jpg' },
        { image: 'bacon/eggs/image3.jpg' }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `dataSource: new_slideshow` instead of `data_source: new_slideshow`

Comment: Alas, I have already tried this one. Both return the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Galleria.get(0).load(new_slideshow);
```

which is, in fact, the same as mhenrys answer